# What is the exception thrown by aioredis.Channel.wait_message()?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a code segment as below which is able to get 6 messages every time before an exception is thrown. However, I could not identify what exception is being thrown; I've got the 'True outside' being printed out, so it looks like the exception is thrown at wait_message(), but "except Exception as e" couldn't catch it. Could anyone help?

```
        redisS  = await aioredis.create_connection(('localhost', 6379)) 
        subCh   = aioredis.Channel(self._redis, is_pattern=False)
        await redisS.execute_pubsub('subscribe', subCh)

        try:
            while await subCh.wait_message():
                try:
                    msg = await subCh.get()
                    for q in self._queues:
                        await q.put(msg)
                except:
                    print('inside')
        except aioredis.ChannelClosedError:
            print(subCh.is_active)
            print('ChannelClosedError')
        except Exception as e:
            print(subCh.is_active)
            print(e)
        except:
            print(subCh.is_active)
            print('outside')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting, I've got the answer. At first, I tried

```
except:
    print(sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Then I've got the <class 'GeneratorExit'>. So, I can finally catch the exception by

```
except GeneratorExit:
   print('caught you')
```

Comment: You can catch other such exceptions it by catching `BaseException` instead of `Exception`. But you should be very careful before actually doing so - a `GeneratorExit` exception leaking to user code might indicate a bug elsewhere in the code, which catching the exception could hide.